Avalonia tabcontrol: SelectedIndex snapping back to 0 when ItemsSource is updating
I have a tab control whose items source updates approximately once per second. Every time it does update, the selected index of the tabs snaps back to zero (first tab).
I experimented with a lot of things but feel I'm somehow missing out on a standard solution.
My code looks like this:
<TabControl 
                ItemsSource="{Binding BettingEvents}"
                Name="EventsTab"
                SelectedIndex="{Binding PriceIndex}"
                SelectionChanged="EventsTab_OnSelectionChanged"
                >
                <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding BetfairEvent.Name}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
                <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="apiNgSampleCode:BettingEvent">
                        <StackPanel>    
                        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MarketPrices}"
                                 ></ListBox>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
            </TabControl>

I tried controlling the bound variable PriceIndex elsewhere but it seems several events were fired that snapped it back to zero and it got out of hand.

Can you add the source code for the ViewModel?  How are you updating the source every minute?
